# Multiline search and replace using C#/class Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've some stored procedures that contain stuff like this:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, COUNT(*) AS "COUNT" INTO temporaryTable
FROM tableA
WHERE columnA = "A"
  AND ISNULL(columnB, "B") = "B"
GROUP BY columnA, columnB
HAVING columnA = "A"
  AND ISNULL(columnB, "B") = "B"
SELECT * FROM temporaryTable -- There is not necessary to have an empty line between two instructions.
```

As said, there are procedures, so many instructions are in the same script.

I load each of theses procedures in a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that contains the same script that shown above).

I want to remove the HAVING part if (and only `IF`!). It is exactly the same as in the WHERE part (as above).

So I immediatly thought at the regular expressions.

I've something like this:

```
    static string RemoveHaving(Match m)
    {
        if (m.Groups[3].Value == m.Groups[7].Value)
        { /* WHERE == HAVING */
            Console.WriteLine("Same");
            return string.Concat(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[9].Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Not Same");
        return m.Groups[0].Value;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // For the example:
        StringBuilder procedure = new StringBuilder();
        procedure.Append(@"
            SELECT columnA, columnB, COUNT(*) AS "COUNT" INTO temporaryTable
            FROM tableA
            WHERE columnA = "A"
              AND ISNULL(columnB, "B") = "B"
            GROUP BY columnA, columnB
            HAVING columnA = "A"
              AND ISNULL(columnB, "B") = "B"
            SELECT * FROM temporaryTable -- There is not necessary to have an empty line between two instructions.");

        Regex reg = new Regex(@"((.*)where(.*)([\s^]+)group\s*by(.*)([\s^]+))having(.*)([\s^]+(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE))",
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |
            RegexOptions.Multiline);

        string newProcedure = reg.Replace(procedure, (MatchEvaluator)RemoveHaving);
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        Console.WriteLine(newProcedure);
        Console.WriteLine("---");
    }
```

It works, but it does not seem to be the best way...

How do I detect safely the end of the HAVING?

How would you manage this work?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't more trouble than it's worth? That's my first thought on this.

Comment: This is obviously not the real example and although you have explained what you are trying to do you haven't explained the problem you are trying to solve so it is not very easy to give you constructive help here.

Comment: Just a hint on how your where clause is constructed.  The way you have used the ISNULL function could hurt the query performance as SQL Server can't use an index on this in an effective way.  Your where clause should be WHERE columnA="A" AND (columnB="B" OR columnB IS NULL)

Comment: @Justin: no, this causes a lot of (performance) problems and I want to remove it.

Comment: @Andrew: As said, I want to remove all having clauses that are identical to the where one. For the ISNULL, it's only an example (and I'm not using MS-SQL Server ;))

Comment: After reading your comment on the first answer about having to "parse (>6000 procedures)", I'm guessing you are working on some sort of legacy system, where the stored proc development sprawled out of control over the history of the project?  And now you are trying to do a bulk update of those procedures to remove redundant HAVING clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought is this:

```
string pattern = @"WHERE\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+HAVING\s+\1\s+(SELECT|$)";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, @"WHERE $1 SELECT");
```

However, this will only work if the statement is immediately followed by the SELECT keyword or an end-of-line. Different use of whitespace in the conditionals will also throw it off, as will reordering of subclauses. If you want something that's going to do this in a robust way, it's going to be VERY complicated without some kind of specialized SQL parser/optimizer.

Comment: In 99% of all procedures I need to parse (>6,000 procedures), the having clause is a copy/paste of the where clause, so I think this will do easily the biggest part of the job ! :)

Comment: Hum, can you just explain this part : `([\s\S]*?)` ? Thanks

Comment: @Arnaud - The `[\s\S]` is similar to `.`, except that it will also match carriage returns. The `*?` quantifier means (roughly) that it can match any number of characters but will stop as soon as it reaches the next `HAVING` keyword. For more info, check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Hope that helps.